# ¿Que sucede si no liberas memoria reservada para un arreglo?

Tags: c++, abogado-del-lenguaje

¿Qué sucede si no liberas la memoria reservada para un arreglo?
Esa es toda mi duda, se llena la memoria? O que pasa?

Comment: Añado a la respuesta de PaperBirdMaster que el asunto puede ser más o menos grave según tu programa termine pronto o esté mucho tiempo en ejecución, y según la reserva de memoria sin liberar ocurra o no dentro de un bucle. Por ejemplo, un servidor que reserve memoria cada vez que recibe un cliente, pero luego no la libere, sería un problema muy grave, pues a medida que llegan clientes irá consumiendo más y más memoria y además el servidor permanece siempre en ejecución. Un hola mundo que olvide liberar memoria no es problema pues en cuanto finalice, el sistema la liberará.

Answer (score 6):

En general, no liberar memoria que has solicitado manualmente (usando el operador `new`) produce lo que se conoce como "[Fuga de memoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuga_de_memoria)" o en Inglés "*memory leak*", esto sucede tanto si la memoria es un arreglo como si es un único objeto (el resaltado es mío):

> Una fuga de memoria (más conocido por el término inglés *memory leak*) es un error de software que ocurre cuando un bloque de memoria reservada no es liberada en un programa de computación. Comúnmente ocurre porque se pierden todas las referencias a esa área de memoria antes de haberse liberado.
>
> Dependiendo de la cantidad de memoria perdida y el tiempo que el programa siga en ejecución, **este problema puede llevar al agotamiento de la memoria disponible en la computadora**.

Esta idea es correcta y es la que debemos interiorizar y usar como dogma, pero no se ajusta del todo a la realidad de los sistemas operativos modernos. Nuestro programa no es el que gestiona la memoria, esta tarea la delega en el sistema operativo.

Dado que el sistema operativo lleva el registro de qué memoria ha solicitado cada programa, puede inferir qué memoria no ha sido liberada al finalizar un programa e igualmente liberarla ¿Significa esto que no debemos responsabilizarnos de la memoria? ¡No!, esa decisión la tomará el sistema operativo cuando el programa no sea responsable de la memoria (es decir, cuando éste haya finalizado) por lo que una gestión irresponsable de la memoria puede dar lugar a un agotamiento de la misma durante la ejecución y/o problemas serios de rendimiento.